# REST API Lists/GetByTitle ignores query parameters

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-rest-api

We have a SharePoint 2013 farm. Since a few days ago, all REST API item queries which used the

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle({listTitle})/Items?$select=ID
```

endpoint pattern started to ignore the query parameters (e.g. $select, $filter, $top, $expand).

The behavior is faulty on all web applications, on all site collections and on all lists (tested randomly).

On the other hand, the endpoints which use the list GUID work as expected:

```
_api/web/lists(guid'{listId}')/Items?$select=ID
_api/web/lists/GetById('{listId}')/Items?$select=ID
```

By inspecting the SPLogs, I noticed that the faulty request seems to include all the default fields in the CAML Query (where only ID should be included). The CAML Query for the requests done with `listId` look as expected in the logs. There was no SP farm update or patch, except a few Windows Server security updates.

Anyone can suggest what to check?

Comment: The issue is gone, not sure is any server / service restart fixed it, as the farm is managed by some other team. Will update the question if there's any conclusion.